# use core-image in 3d

Tags: cocoa, opengl, 3d, core-image, core-video

i have a working `Core Video` setup (a frame captured from a USB camera via `QTKit`) and the current frame is rendered as a texture on an arbitary plane in 3d space in a subclassed `NSOpenGLView`. so far so good but i would like to use some `Core Image` filter on this frame.
i now have the basic code setup and it renders my unprocessed video frame like before, but the final processed output `CIImage` is rendererd as a screen aligned quad into the view. it feels like a image blitted over my 3d rendering. this is what i do not want!

i am looking for a way to process my video frame (a `CVOpenGLTextureRef`) with `Core Image` and just render the resulting image on my plane in 3d.
do i have to use offscreen rendering (store viewport, set new viewport and modelview and perspective matrices and render into a FBO) or is there any easier way?

thanks in advance!

Comment: just in case somebody is interested - in the end i used my proposed approach using a OpenGL Frame Buffer Object (FBO). works really well, as expected.
i just hoped there are some neat tricks from apple to let Core Video, Core Image and OpenGL work together more easily .... so if anybody knows, i would still appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)! It's easy to use, and faster than CoreImage processing. It uses predefined, or custom shaders (GLSL)